# How to compile several java class and text file in linux

Tags: java, linux

I have two class: `main.java` and `data.java`. The programming need to read data from a data.txt file first. It works on windows system. But now I use ssh to link a linux server for compile and it does not work.

I put `main.java`, `data.java`, `data.txt` in the same folder. after run `javac data.java && javac main.java` generalize 6 class: `main.class`, `data.class` and some class defined in `main.java`. At last I run `java main`, or `java main && java data` it all shows `NullPointerException`.

The link of `data.txt` in code I use `./data.txt`

Maybe they can not put in the same folder, or some other reasons. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Part of the code for `data.java`:

```
import java.io.EOFException;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;   
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class data{

    private LineNumberReader in; 
    String filename;

    public data(String file){
        filename = file;
        readProblem(); 
        readdis();
        read();
    }
 }
```

The code for part of `main.java`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {   
        //Define parameters of the algorithm   
        String file = new String("./data.txt");
```

Comment: Can you post some code and your stack trace?

Comment: Please post some code that recreates your problem. We call it an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.com). I can't even guess why you get a NullPointerException without it.

Comment: Thanks for remind, I post some code. But the main problem is how to run it on the linux server. I can get the result on windows with small data, but not on linux.

Comment: Just install eclipse unless you have a reason to use CLI...

Comment: Do you launch your java app from the directory of your classes and txt ?

Comment: Maybe it's an uppercase/lowercase problem? (Most) Linux file systems are case sensitive, while Windows isn't, so your program might read e.g. `Data.TXT` on Windows, while on linux, it doesn't, since `Data.TXT` is not the same like `data.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding and different line ending may play a role.

A *BufferedReader.readLine* will strip the possible line endings.

The character set may be set explicitly, for instance to `"Windows-1252"`, Windows Latin-1. For that use

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file, "Windows-1252");
```